Smooth normals look bad when deforming the mesh
I will show the problem using a hand model as an example. I have a hand model that is trying to "save polygons" (not low poly). And to make such a model look good, I smoothed out its normals. But when I try to deform such a mesh, for example by attaching a rig to it, the normals remain the same. This exposes the rough edges of the "polygon saving" mesh. Sometimes this also causes artifacts during shading.

And so the question is: Is there a solution to this problem, besides actually increasing the polygons?

Sharp-edge normals are really meant for non-deforming hardsurface meshes. If your model is so low poly that its shading looks bad without sharpedges then I would see if adding a Weighted Normal modifier smooths it out a bit. But generally people don't put sharp edges on animated meshes, to my knowledge.
